# python image process with multithreading problem

Tags: python, oop, image-processing, python-multithreading

i have a smart door lock project with using mimic passwords and i can take mimic with camera i can detect fingers, smile, eyebrows etc. but all in one script. I want to use class things for it. I construct class build but i have to use multithreading because i have to run more than one method for detect all mimics in one cam. With my code, it opens 2 cam one by one, first opened cam and detect fingers and when i close it open another cam and detect face. how can i make it with one cam?

camera.py https://www.pythonmorsels.com/p/33trh/

FaceLandMarks.py https://www.pythonmorsels.com/p/28jmh/

HandLandMarks.py https://www.pythonmorsels.com/p/33ffw/

HandTrackingModule.py https://www.pythonmorsels.com/p/39jw2/

test.py https://www.pythonmorsels.com/p/3a2e5/

Comment: create `captureMode = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` outside classes and send `captureMode` to classes as parameter.

Comment: `Threading` and `Process` need target without `()` - `target=handdetector.getPosition` and `target=facedetector.run` - and `start()` will later use `()` to run it - `target()`.

Comment: camera may not work with `Process` because processes can't send opened camera - and every process would have to open it on your own. But this can make problem when two processes will try to open the same camera at the same time. Camera can be open only in one process. It would need to run Camera in one process and use `Queue` to send image to other processes.

Comment: creating Threads or Processes in while-loop it big waste of time. You should run loop inside Threads or Processes and create threads or processes only once.

Comment: Please read [mre]. In Stack Overflow, questions have to be self-contained, putting key information about the question on 3rd party sites is not allowed because the links will rot, making the question meaningless. Please [edit] your post to contain a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest is to create camera outside classes and send it to classes as parameter

```
captureMode = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

FaceLandMarks(captureMode).run()
HandLandMarks(captureMode).run()
# etc.

captureMode.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
class LandMarksFace:  # without `Camera
    
    def __init__(self, camera):

        self.camera = camera

        # ... code ...

    def run(self):

        # ... code ...

        success, img = self.camera.read()

        # ... code ...
```

---

And if you really need to use class `Camera` then create it in `__init__` and set instace to all classes

```
class Camera():

    def __init__(self):
        self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def getCamera(self):
        return self.camera
```

```
cam = Camera()

FaceLandMarks(cam).run()
HandLandMarks(cam).run()
# etc.

cam.getCamera().release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
class LandMarksFace:  # without `Camera
    
    def __init__(self, camera):

        self.camera = camera

        # ... code ...

    def run(self):

        # ... code ...

        success, img = self.camera.getCamera().read()

        # ... code ...
```

Comment: when i make it, it worked as a camera class but it open 2 cam again

Comment: maybe you mean two windows - you have diffferent names in `imshow()` - `Image` and `image` - upper and lower `i` - and this makes problem. You have to use exactly the same name in both windows: `Image` or `image`

Comment: I guess i found the problem. I use twice imshow and cam opened twice. how can i take it in camera class and use one? when i made it it gives me another bug ""cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'cvtColor' > Overload resolution failed: > - src is not a numerical tuple > - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'""

Comment: better create new question on new page and you will have space to show all code and full error message

Comment: as I show in code - you should open camera outside classes and send it to classes as parameter (and don't close it in classes but after all classes). And `imshow()` should use exactly the same name but you have two different `Image` (with upper `I`) and `image` (with lower `i`)